# How do I install Python 3.9?

Tags: software-installation, python3

I want to install Python 3.9 in Ubuntu. When I run `sudo apt-get python` in the terminal it says that it will install Python 2 which I don't want. When I type `sudo apt-get install python3.9` it shows that it is an invalid operation.

How do I install Python 3.9?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python3.9
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9'

Answer (score 21):

As you're "new to Linux", I won't suggest compiling from source. Instead, there is a PPA that you'll need to add to `apt` so that you can use 3.9. Here are the steps:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Update `apt` and confirm that you have the prerequisites installed:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install software-properties-common
   ```
2. The PPA you'll need to add is maintained by "deadsnakes", so let's add that:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
   ```

   You'll be asked if you want to continue. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to do so.
3. Update `apt` again:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
4. Install Python 3.9:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3.9
   ```
5. Confirm that the installation was successful:

   ```
   python3.9 --version
   ```

   You should see:

   ```
   Python 3.9.1+
   ```

That's all there is to it. When you use anything that specifically requires Python 3.9, be sure to use `python3.9` as the command, not `python` or `python3`.

**Warning: Do not** remove the default version of Python(3.x) which was preinstalled in Ubuntu, even if you install Python 3.9. Removing the default python version may break your system.

Comment: What a joke lmao. 'deadsnakes' , are you kidding me? Very professional stuff going on there

Comment: @Anthony I don't see a problem with the name -- deadsnakes is a repository of old python versions, so, the name fits

Comment: I did remove, by mistake, the default version (3.5), because of one of the answers out there told to do so. How do I fix that "broken stuff"?

Comment: I ran all of these commands. The "install" of python3.9 was over in less than 1 second and says "The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required" with a huge list. When I run `python3.9 --version` it returns `python3.9 command not found`. `python3 --version` returns `Python 3.5.2`. Now what?

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu 16.04 is no longer supported by the deadsnakes respository

Comment: Yes, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install synaptic using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Then, open synaptic and click on search button. Type "Python 3.9" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now click on the box next to python3.9 and click on mark for installation. On top click on Apply button.

[image: see image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running at least 20.04 with the focal-updates repository enabled. Looking at the output of the command `apt-cache policy python3.9` will tell you if available when used in the `Terminal` program. Using `apt install python3.9` if it is available can possible install it for you if the dependencies are right.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.9&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all